# How to observe sockets until unsubscribing in Rxjava

Tags: java, rx-java, serversocket

I wrote a small piece of code which takes a parameter ObjectInputStream and observe the data on a socket. The problem raise once readObject() function returns "null" and since the function observeSocket(ObjectInputStream in) takes only Object the subscriber executes onError() function and terminates the program.

But what I need is to continue observing sockets for Objects and return only if an Object is observed over the socket and only when observer unsubscribes should the function terminates its functionality. How could I modify the code to achieve the required functionality.

```
public Observable<Object> observeSocket(ObjectInputStream in){
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        while(!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
            subscriber.onNext(getData(in));
        }

        subscriber.onCompleted();

    });
}

public Object getData(ObjectInputStream in){

    Object streamData = null;

    try{

        streamData = in.readObject();
    }

    catch(IOException e){
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return streamData;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `Observable.create(OnSubscribe)` because making backpressure aware and contract-compliant Observables is tricky business. This is a good candidate for using `Observable.create(SyncOnSubscribe)`:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = ...;

Observable<Object> objects = 
  Observable.create(
    SyncOnSubscribe.createStateless(observer -> {
      try {
          Object value = ois.readObject();
          // you decide how end of file is indicated
          // a common strategy is to write a null object
          // to the end of the Object stream.
          if (value == END_OF_FILE) {
              observer.onCompleted();
          } else {
              observer.onNext(value);
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          observer.onError(e);
      }
    }));
```

Comment: Did you test this cost on your machine. SyncOnSubscribe generic signature is different from what the Action return value is thus raise an compilation error and syntax error.

Comment: createStateless only takes Action1() and observer.onNext or any other functions can't be implemented.

Comment: forgot to put the Observable.create in. Compiles fine for me using rxjava 1.2.1

Comment: How about using Flowables in RxJava 2.x. Does you experiment a bit and can we use Flowables instead of Observables.

Comment: The same functionality exists in `Flowable` in RxJava 2.x but the API will be slightly different.

Comment: SyncOnSubscribe supports backpressure. So if I have a fast producer and slow consumer, what will happen and what steps does it take. Would it discard or creates buffer or stop the observer for a brief moment until subscriber catches up.

Comment: What does the InputStream you're using represent? A file? A network call? If it's a network call then your the sender's io buffer may start to grow in combination with some growth on your machine's io buffer. If the stream cannot be processed fast enough and can overflow available memory then you can use `Transformers.onBackpressureBufferToFile` from rxjava-extras to offload the stream to disk on the receiving end.

Comment: The observable function use in.readObject() from network stream. Here the observable is the producer of objects and the subscriber which just gets the object from subscriber sends its to a queue.  Now I need to have a function which sends the stream of events into the queue to be sent to other function also. For that I want to use observable on the queue but don't know how efficient I could do.